# Upgrading Magento from 1.7 to 1.9 causes error: The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I just upgraded our Magento instance from v1.7 to v1.9. And one of the stores websites is now receiving an error when the cart gets updated:

> The address total model should be extended from **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract**.

I came across [this similar post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/errorthe-address-total-model-should-be-extended-from-mage-sales-model-quote-add), where the OP encountered the same error, but it looks like it was caused by a different problem.

I grepped for the string `The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract.`, and can see it originates from the file **base/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Collector.php**. Here's the method containing the logic throwing the error:

```
    /**
     * Init model class by configuration
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $totalCode
     * @param array $totalConfig
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
     */
    protected function _initModelInstance($class, $totalCode, $totalConfig)
    {
        $model = Mage::getModel($class);
        if (!$model instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract.')
            );
        }

        $model->setCode($totalCode);
        $this->_modelsConfig[$totalCode]= $this->_prepareConfigArray($totalCode, $totalConfig);
        $this->_modelsConfig[$totalCode]= $model->processConfigArray(
            $this->_modelsConfig[$totalCode],
            $this->_store
        );

        return $model;
    }
```

I took the advice posted in the other thread and dumped the content of `$model` to see what class it was *actually* an instance of, the result:

```
object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Nominal)#358 (5) {
  ["_code":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_address":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_canAddAmountToAddress":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_canSetAddressAmount":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_itemRowTotalKey":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

So the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector::_initModelInstance()` 
method within **base/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Collector.php** is requiring the `$method` to be an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract`, but it's actually an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Nominal`.

After grepping around for a bit, I can see that the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Nominal` class is declared within the **base/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Nominal.php** file, and when I open it up, I see:

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Nominal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
```

`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector::_initModelInstance()` is requiring `$method` to be an instance of *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_**Abstract***, but it's *actually* an instance of *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_**Nominal***, which **is** an instance of *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_**Abstract***.

So instead of:

> `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` => `$method`

It's:

> `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` => `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Nominal` => `$method`

I'm not quite sure what to make of this. The abstract class *is* being extended, it's just one "level" further back than it's expected to be.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed any third party extension for checkout or cart?